# If the degree distribution of a network conforms to the long-tail distribution, but it is not a scale-free network, what properties does it have?

Tags: graph-theory, network

For a real network, I plotted its degree distribution and found it conforms to the long-tail distribution. It means that most of the nodes in the network are connected to only a few nodes, and there are very few nodes that have a much higher degree than most other nodes. However, when I checked whether it belongs to a scale-free network (using `powerlaw` package in R language), the results showed it doesn't belong to a scale-free network. Thus, what **properties** can I get? Can I say that this network is not vulnerable to random attacks at nodes?

Comment: What “long-tail distribution”? What’s your definition of scale-free network? There are at least some definitions of the latter that are only based on the presence of a power-law distribution, which in turn is long-tailed.

Comment: The typical feature of the long-tail distribution is that most of the nodes in the network are connected to only a few nodes, and there are very few nodes that have a much higher degree than most other nodes. However, when I used `powerlaw` package (in R language) to test, the result shows that it doesn't belong to a power-law distribution.

Comment: Please [edit] that information into the question (sorry, I forgot to mention that earlier). Also please be aware that for sufficiently large datasets, statistical tests (such as `powerlaw`) will register the slightest deviation from a target distribution and such deviations are almost always there, e.g., simply because your degrees are integers.

Comment: Yes, it is a large network with 355,642 nodes and 372,434 edges.